# Seriously, Stack Overflow? Programing?

Tags: bug, status-completed, advertising, survey, survey-2019

There's an ad on my Stack Overflow front page right now that reads:

> Do you know 2019's fastest-growing progra**m**ing language?

[image]

Can we get this fixed please? It doesn't really inspire confidence in the results of the developer survey.

Comment: Actually [both are correct](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/244280/programming-versus-programing-which-is-preferred) it seems

Comment: From the post @GBlodgett links: "But the weight of real-world usage is overwhelmingly in favor of doubling the m, as [this Ngram chart of programed (blue line) and programing (red line) versus programmed (green line) and programming (yellow line) for the period 1930–2005 indicates](https://books.google.com/ngrams/chart?content=programed%2Cprograming%2Cprogrammed%2Cprogramming&year_start=1930&year_end=2005&corpus=15&smoothing=0&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cprogramed%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cprograming%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cprogrammed%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cprogramming%3B%2Cc0)"

Comment: Browser spell checker shows "programing" with a red underline. Definitely a bug!!!1

Comment: Just to be safe, we should add some more Ms, in case one gets stripped. I feel 5 should be sufficient

Comment: Just to add even more confusion to this: *"Do you know what's the 2019 fastest-growing programming language?"*, which I believe was the original intent, asks us if we know **what** is that popular, rising language. However, supposing that this language is COBOL, the way the question in the image was worded can make people understand it as: *"Do you know COBOL?"*.

Comment: Eye halve rune this add threw the spelling chequer that came with my pea sea. It did not marque any miss steaks four my revue, and eye kin knot sea any mist aches their.

Comment: @CodyGray [r/BoneAppleTea](https://www.reddit.com/r/BoneAppleTea/)

Comment: @GerardoFurtado and there's no problem with either interpretation in this case.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You're right, that's not the primary spelling. We fixed it, so the next time you see that ad, "programming" will have two m's instead of one. Thanks!

Comment: Hi Kristina, if this is now fixed, can you edit the question to include the [meta-tag:status-completed] tag (only moderators or employees can use these tags, or I'd do it).

Comment: Thanks @TylerH for being better at this part of my job than I am. :)

Comment: Part of the benefit of having thousands of participating foot soldiers paying attention :-)

Comment: To be more inclusive, given that both spellings are correct, perhaps you could make it "program(m)ing".